# Get all logged users in Spring Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I would like to get list of all users which are currently logged in my application. I know, that I should inject `SessionRegistry` in my code to call `getAllPrincipals()` method. Unfortunatelly, I always get empty list. It seems that `SessionRegistry` is not populate and I don't know how to make it. I know, that on StackOverflow there are similar questions, but I still have problem with solving my problem. Firstly I add to my web.xml this code:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

As I know it allows to get information about lifecycle (create, destroy) of sessions. And that's all. I have big problem with moving forward. My file with security beans is presented below:

```
<beans:bean id="successAuth" class="pl.fp.microblog.auth.SuccessAuth"/>
<beans:bean id="failureAuth" class="pl.fp.microblog.auth.FailureAuth"/>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/profile/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"         
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successAuth"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureAuth"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"           
        login-processing-url="/login_processing_url"
    />          
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout_processing_url"/>  
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
    </session-management>
</http>

<beans:bean id="saltProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
    <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="pl.fp.microblog.auth.UserService">
    <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <security:salt-source ref="saltProvider"/>
        </password-encoder>         
    </security:authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here I call getAllPrinciples() method:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class SiteController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "profile/{login}")  
    public String profilePage(@PathVariable String login, HttpServletRequest req) throws SQLException {     
        ...
        sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size()
        ...     
        return "profile";               
    }
}
```

I tried to add `session-managemenent` code into my `http`, `ConcurrentSessionFilter` and similar things, but in fact I don't understand it. And the documentation is too complex for me. Does anyone could help me and tell step by step what to do next? Which beans should I add?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are almost there. The only thing you've probably missed is the use of `session-registry-alias`. By using that attribute on the `concurrency-control` element you expose the session registry, so that it can be injected to your own beans. See the [reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-concurrency-control).

So what you need is:

```
<http auto-config="true">
...
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Now you have a reference to the session registry that will be populated by the `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` which is set up implicitly by the above configuration. To use it you would just inject it to your bean as normal:

```
<bean class="YourOwnSessionRegistryAwareBean">
    <property sessionRegistry="sessionRegistry"/>
</bean>
```

Please note that the above configuration will also restrict the number of concurrent sessions a user may have. If you don't want this restriction, you will have to forgo the convenience of the namespace configuration, because the namespace schema doesn't allow you to set the `max-sessions` attribute to -1. If you need help on how to wire up the necessary beans manually, the reference doc gives [detailed instructions on that](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#concurrent-sessions).

Comment: I add this to my `http` element, but I still get empty list after call `getAllPrincipals()`.

Comment: Are you sure that you call `getAllPrincipals()` on the `SessionRegistry` instance obtained like shown in my answer?

Comment: My `http` element is the same as your code. `SessionRegistry` injection I did like this: `@Autowired private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;`. When application is running I call method like that: `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size()` but it returns 0.

Comment: Is that after successfully logging in with a user? Weird, because I tested the config before posting my answer, and it works, I can see the user's session in the registry.

Comment: Yes, I call this method after log in. I have usually one or two logged users at the same moment, so I should get `getAllPrincipals().size()` equals 1 or 2.

Comment: I edited my main post. A added fragment of my controller and I also updated `http` element.

Comment: By the way, if you autowire it, you don't even need the alias to the registry bean, I think. If it still doesn't work make sure you actually have an authenticated http session. 
Also you could perhaps try a debug session with a breakpoint on `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.onAuthentication()` checking if the session registry instance used there to register the new session is really the same as the one you use when calling `getAllPrincipals()`.

Comment: Well... after `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.onAuthentication()` method there is 1 entry in sessionRegistry (see: http://i.imgur.com/S1bmg.png). But in my controller it's still empty list. I think that wrong `sessionRegistry` is injected. But how to fix it?

Comment: Moreover, I inject `@Autowired private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;` to class which implements `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` (which is run after succesful log in) and it works. I don't know why I can't do the same injection in my controller.

Comment: I noticed than I don't even need `session-management` element in `http`. But I still get correct number of logged users only in `authentication-success-handler-ref` class. In my controller I get always access to other instance of SessionRegistry.