# Spring Security logoff a user while runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing a spring based web application which is using Spring Security with a DaoAuthenticationProvider. Therefor I created a User class which has a boolean `isEnabled();` method because of it implements Springs UserDetails interface. So if a user is "not enabled", this user will not be able to login anymore. So far so good.

If I disable a user while runtime which is still logged in, (it seems that) this user stays logged in until the http-session ends, but I want that the user logs out immediately after I set him disabled. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297577/get-all-logged-users-in-spring-security, you need to use SessionRegistry somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a running web application which is capable of disabling users, I will show you how to lock out those users at runtime.

The basic idea is to reauthenticate each request with refreshed user details. For that purpose you'll need a custom [`SecurityContextRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html) which
discards user details that are saved in the http session.

```
public class RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository implements SecurityContextRepository {

    private final SecurityContextRepository delegate;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository(final SecurityContextRepository delegate, final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        Assert.notNull(delegate);
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService);
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityContext loadContext(final HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = delegate.loadContext(requestResponseHolder);

        if(securityContext.getAuthentication() == null) {
            return securityContext;
        }

        Authentication principal = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());

        //this code has to be modified when using remember me service, jaas or a custom authentication token
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword());

        securityContext.setAuthentication(token);
        saveContext(securityContext, requestResponseHolder.getRequest(), requestResponseHolder.getResponse());
        return securityContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveContext(final SecurityContext context, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        delegate.saveContext(context, request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsContext(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return delegate.containsContext(request);
    }
}
```

`RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository` simply wraps default `SecurityContextRepository`, that is [`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html). Thereby you don't need to worry about session timeout or storing the [`SecurityContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html) by yourself. In the `loadContext` method user details become refreshed with `userDetailsService` and are written back to the `SecurityContext` before handing it out to the caller.

Don't pass users [authorities](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) to [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html) constructor. Otherwise token is marked as authenticated and the reauthentication is never triggererd!

Beware that `RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository` restricts you to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. If you want to use, for instance, Jaas, Spring Security remember me or a custom authentication token that doesn't derive from `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` you need to adapt  `RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository` to your needs.

Add `RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository` to your security configuration.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" security-context-repository-ref="refreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository">
    <security:intercept-url ... />
    <security:form-login ... />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<bean id="refreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository" class="security.RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

That's it. Your logged in but disabled users get redirected back to the login page on their next page request.

Here´s a fully functional [example](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/spring-security-disable-user/spring-mvc).

Comment: How would you configure this with java config? I have configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.securityContext().securityContextRepository(new RefreshingUserDetailsSecurityContextRepository())
but this class requires constructor parameters?