# Customize @AuthenticatedPrincipal to reattach to session

Tags: spring-security

My `AuthenticatedPrincipal` is a Hibernate managed entity. When I use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` out of the box, I get a detached entity and run in to `LazyLoadingExceptions`.

I use the `OpenSessionInViewPattern`.

I would like to "reattach" the entity by calling `session.merge(entity)` before it gets passed to the Controller method.

Is there a way to create a extend `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to let's say `@MergedAuthenticationPrincipal` and customize Spring Security to preprocess principals such as these so that I can merge them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't extend [@AuthenticationPrincipal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html) or the underlying [AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) directly, but you could reimplement the functions of [AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) and attach them to your own custom Annotation. In addition, it looks like [AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) supports some sort of use as a base for your own custom Annotation as shown in the [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html).

I'm not exactly clear on the details of how there example works though. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of how to work with building Annotations could explain it for both of us. I myself would probably just go with building my own Annotation using [AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) as a guide and adding your call to merge() in the resolveArgument() method.

Comment: It is possible to configure a custom ArgumentResolver for @AuthenticationPrincipal, if no custom Annotation is desired, but at the time the ArgumentResolver is called, there is not yet a Session, so it is not possible to merge the Entity to an entity Manager.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @cmorris, a custom Resolver is required to fetch the Principal-Object from the Session and reattach it. One can declare a custom `MergedAuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` and add it *before* the original `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` one, so no custom Annotation is required and all Methods using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` automatically get a correctly attached Version of the Principal and access Lazy-Loaded Collections are accessible.

I came up with this solution:
https://gist.github.com/MaZderMind/e415be1c5e15b7c36e07df85a91bb673

On think I'm not happy with is that every Request creates and closes a new `EntityManager`, but at least it's a startingpoint.

If you're looking into this you might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26697333, which helps you to refresh your Principal from the Database on each request, allowing just-in-time changes to his permissions without the need to logout/login again.

Comment: Hmpf. Sorry for the noise. It seems I was to quick; the problem actually was only hidden by me forgetting to call `entityManager.close()` which, in the long run, does not work out :)
After closing the EM, the problem's here again. Meeeh…

Comment: It seems that using a JpaRepository instead of a plain EntityManager somehow does the trick. I updated the Gist above, which now works fine for us.