# Spring Security: how to change user roles without login and logout

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

Spring Security 4.2.4. Java 8

I need to change the permissions of users without re-logging them. It's my service:

```
@Component
public class AuthoritiesUpdater {

    private final UserRoleService userRoleService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthoritiesUpdater(UserRoleService userRoleService) {
        this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleService.findByUser(user);

        List<GrantedAuthority> actualAuthorities = userRoles.stream().map(userRole -> new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Authentication newAuth = new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), actualAuthorities);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
    }
}
```

But there is a trouble. I need to change roles for any user. Let's say I'm manager and I want to change roles for test user. I need to reload the permissions after saving configuration and test user will have new roles when he press F5 button and reload the page without re-login.
But `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` returns authentication object only for current user (manager). I need to get authentication object for changed user to call `new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), actualAuthorities);`. 
Can I get authentication object for any user or can I solve this problem in another way? Maybe I can get authentication object uses session registry?

P.S.: Doing an expired session for user isn't a good option.

Comment: Not the same problem but maybe an answer that works for your use case aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393518/spring-security-logoff-a-user-while-runtime/26697333#26697333

Answer (score 3):

Excellent answer, thanks @virkom!

For newer users, the steps are as follow:

1. Create a list of authorities you want the user to have (including the previous one(s) they had). In this case (below) I created a set so they would be unique.
2. Create an authentication object which matches the user you want to authenticate with their new authorities. In this case, I used a user who was in memory to simplify the example, but database authentication is preferred!
3. Update the security context with the new authentication information. This will have the effect of a refresh of the user's credentials.

A code snippet is shown below:

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));

Authentication reAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user",new 

BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("password"),authorities);  

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(reAuth);
```

Sample code is available on github: https://github.com/aoa4eva/ContextDemo

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit easier than I thought. I have a user.
And I can call `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), actualAuthorities);` instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), actualAuthorities);`.
I don't need to get authentication object. Final version of service:

```
@Component
public class AuthoritiesUpdater {

    private final UserRoleService userRoleService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthoritiesUpdater(UserRoleService userRoleService) {
        this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleService.findByUser(user);

        List<GrantedAuthority> actualAuthorities = userRoles.stream().map(userRole -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), actualAuthorities);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: With `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication` you can only change the currently authenticated principal information, It means that you cannot change the other users'!